# Kubuntu 16.04 black screen after installing a different graphical login screen display manager

Tags: kubuntu, lightdm, kdm

I'm using Kubuntu 16.04. After installing the lightdm graphical login screen display manager, when booting it goes to a black screen. How do I fix this so that Kubuntu will boot normally?

Answer (score 0):

A display manager is a program that provides graphical login capabilities for the X Window system. Change the display manager from lightdm back to the default Kubuntu display manager, kdm. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

This will open up a new window allowing you to select either kdm or lightdm as the default login display manager.

[image]